# How to get branch coverage using bazel with c++

Tags: c++, testing, code-coverage, bazel

I have a project which needs to use bazel to get the code brach coverage, however, I only get the lines and functions coverage, how can I get the branch coverage
the bazel coverage command is

```
bazel coverage $unit_test_path --nocache_test_results --coverage_report_generator="@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main" --combined_report=lcov --instrumentation_filter="//src[/:]" --experimental_cc_coverage

genhtml ./bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat -o ../coverage_output |tail -n 2 >genhtml.out
```

Comment: You need to add `--branch-coverage` to `genhtml` to see the branch coverage.